# Vector<vector<int>> Push_back

Tags: c++, c++17

I wanted to store a graph, so I tried using vector<vector>, but I encountered an array out-of-bounds error while reading the graph. So, I switched to using vector[N], and now the program runs correctly. I want to know why the first approach caused an error, while the second approach works fine. This program is a simple topological sorting, and I am using the g++ 12.2.0 compiler.

here is accept

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

using i64 = long long;

int n, m;
const int N = 1e6 + 10;
vector<int> edge[N];
int adj[N];
int q[N];

inline void toposort() {
    int front = 1, rear = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (adj[i] == 0){
            q[++rear] = i;
        }
    }
    while (front <= rear) {
        int s = q[front];
        ++front;
        for (auto c : edge[s]) {
            if (--adj[c] == 0) {
                q[++rear] = c;
            }
        }
    }
    if (rear == n) {
        cout << "Yes\n"; 
    } else {
        cout << "No\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);


    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; ++i) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        edge[x].push_back(y);
        ++adj[y];
    }

    toposort();

    return 0;
}
```

this is wrong

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

using i64 = long long;

int n, m;
const int N = 1e6 + 10;
vector< vector<int> > edge; 
int adj[N];
int q[N];

inline void toposort() {
    int front = 1, rear = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (adj[i] == 0){
            q[++rear] = i;
        }
    }
    while (front <= rear) {
        int s = q[front];
        ++front;
        for (auto c : edge[s]) {
            if (--adj[c] == 0) {
                q[++rear] = c;
            }
        }
    }
    if (rear == n) {
        cout << "Yes\n"; 
    } else {
        cout << "No\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);


    cin >> n >> m;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; ++i) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        edge[x].push_back(y);
        ++adj[y];
    }

    toposort();

    return 0;
}
```

input:
4 4
1 2
2 3
3 4
1 4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7g4I.png)

I tried initializing the 'edge' array and even declared it as a local variable, but I'm still encountering an array out-of-bounds issue. Can someone with expertise explain what might be causing this problem? Thank you.

Comment: `edge` is empty, `edge[s]` and `edge[x]` are mistakenly used.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `edge[x].push_back(y)` assumes that the array or vector element `edge[x]` already exists.
In the first version, you declare an array of vectors `vector<int> edge[N]`, so `edge[x]` is an existing element of that array.
In the second version, `vector< vector<int> > edge` is an empty vector, so accessing its element (`edge[x]`) is Undefined Behavior. To make it work, you can construct vector having `N` elements like this: `vector< vector<int> > edge(N)`.

Comment: thx，your are right, it's my wrong